# How to fade out buttons on image slider at start and end of array

Tags: javascript

I have two buttons that when clicked move through an image slider, they are `#prevtBtn` and `#nextBtn`.

Could anyone give me some help with adding an if statement to check if the image being displayed is at the start of the array and then fading out the `prevtBtn` and then checking if the array is at the end and fading out the `nextBtn`.

See below for code.

```js
TweenLite.set('.image_container',{perspective:700});

var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide'),
    tl = new TimelineLite({
        paused:true
    }),
    i, l;

for(i=0, l=slides.length ; i<l; i++) {
    var D = document.createElement('div');

    D.className = 'Dot';
    D.id = 'Dot' + i;

    D.addEventListener('click', function(){
        tl.seek(this.id).pause();
    });

    document.getElementById('Dots').appendChild(D);

    if(i!=0) {
        tl.addPause('Dot'+i);
    };

    if(i!=slides.length-1) {
        tl
            .to(slides[i], 0.5, {
                scale: .8,
                ease: Back.easeOut
            })
            .to(slides[i], 0.7, {
                xPercent: -100,
                rotationY: 80
            }, 'L' + i) 
            .from(slides[i+1], 0.7, {
                xPercent: 100,
                rotationY: -80
            }, 'L' + i)
            .to('#Dot' + i, 0.7, {
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(102,255,0,1)'
            }, 'L' + i)
            .from(slides[i+1], 0.5, {
                scale: .8,
                ease: Back.easeIn
            });
    } 
};

function GO(e){
    var SD = isNaN(e) ? (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail) : e;

    if(SD<0) {
        tl.play()
    } else {
        tl.reverse()
    };
};

document.getElementById('nextBtn').addEventListener("click", function() {
    GO(-1);
});
document.getElementById('prevtBtn').addEventListener("click", function() {
    GO(1)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```js
if (slides[0].offsetParent === null) {
    fade(document.getElementById('prevBtn');
}
if (slides[lis.length-1].offsetParent === null) {
    fade(document.getElementById('nextBtn'));
}
function fade(element) {
    var op = 1;  // initial opacity
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (op <= 0.1){
            clearInterval(timer);
            element.style.display = 'none';
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
        op -= op * 0.1;
    }, 50);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: hi thanks for that, the problem I am having is that any new code placed inside the for loop stops the program from working, I have tried to place it in a variety of places.